# Am I Understanding Objects in Ruby Correctly?

Tags: ruby, oop, object

I feel this is fundamental to my understanding of Ruby and object-oriented programming in general, so I'm asking this fairly simplistic question here at the risk of looking foolish. I've been toying around with irb. I've created my first ever class:

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > class Person
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002?>   attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname, :gender
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 > person_instance = Person.new
 => #<Person:0x007f9b7a9a0f70> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :005 > person_instance.firstname = "Bob"
 => "Bob" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :006 > person_instance.lastname = "Dylan"
 => "Dylan"
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > person_instance.gender = "male"
 => "male"
```

So `Person.new` is my object, right? Or is my object the combination of `class Person` and the attributes I've defined for that class?

Comment: Technically they're both objects.  `Person.new` is an instance of the `Person` class.

Comment: +1 for having the guts of asking the question despite the risk of looking foolish. "The only stupid question is the one that isn't asked" goes a saying...

Comment: Generally, it's confusing to most people to call classes objects, as objects are most commonly referred to an instance of a class. I'd much rather people say "class" when they refer to a class, and object to an instantiated instance.

Comment: `Person.new.class #=> Person` `Person.class #=> Class`. `Class.class #=> Class`. `ClassClass` had me cursing when I was first learning OOP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your object is the *result* of running `Person.new`, which you've captured in `person_instance`.

In ruby, attributes don't actually exist until they are first written, so before `person_instance.firstname = "Bob"`, your instance has no attributes.  After executing this statement it has a `@firstname` attribute, but no others.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.  Everything in ruby is an object.  So when you create a new class 'person' it itself is an object of type class.

Comment: Do you mean "new class `Person` it itself ..."?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm yes, that's what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

Strings are also objects, so after you've done

```
person_instance.firstname = "Bob"
```

then `person_instance.firstname` refers to a string object. So you can call

```
# Returns String, indicating that the object returned by 
# person_instance.firstname is an instance of the String class.
person_instance.firstname.class 
# Returns a not very informative number, but indicates that it is its own object
person_instance.firstname.object_id
```